# Issue in Google doc viewer

Tags: html, iframe, google-docs, google-document-viewer

i am try to show pdf files using googledoc viewer for that i am using the following code

```
 <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?
  url=http://sitename/Content/Bullettin/Data/tredsetter.pdf &embedded=true" 
  style="width:790px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but in my website page loads in iframe shows the following message

```
 Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source.
 Verify that the document still exists.
 You can also try to download the original document by clicking here.
```

When i am clicking on that "here" link, my document is loaded in iframe. I cann't understand what is the problem . please help me

Comment: You probably need to URL-encode the URL parameter.

Comment: How can i encode the above url?? http%3A%2F%2sitename%2FContent%2FBullettin%2FData%2Ftredsetter.pdf, is that ok, but i got the same answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=URL&embedded=true" style="width:790px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Try it now,is it ok?

Comment: thank you very much , can you please remove the full url in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your file doesn't exist at all...check the link in the code,it shows 404 Error

Comment: i am not paste the full url